# Event after big bang that cause dark matter

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, dark-matter, matter

When the universe was formed by the [Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), what was the event that made some matter visible to us, while some became dark matter?

Comment: This is clearly outside of the realm of established science, unfortunately. Any kind of answer you could get would be pure speculation. P.S. I'm not sure why you're getting vigorously downvoted, it's a beginner question but I don't think there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: I only have a beginner's knowledge in Physics, so whenever I watch videos by Michio Kaku, Brian Greene and many other physicist, my brain starts the explode with fascinating questions, thats why I thought to post some question in order to gain some knowledge in order to think systematically 

Comment: We don’t yet understand enough about dark matter to know how it got made.

Comment: It's definitely possible to answer this with respect to specific widely discussed classes of dark matter model. Maybe it would be better to ask about each model specifically, though (e.g. WIMPs, PBHs, axions, sterile neutrinos). Also there are really two questions here, one about dark matter creation and the other about baryogenesis.

Comment: Certainly answerable and a valid question. Here's an article discussing, at an introductory level, ideas for the origin of WIMPS. Difference scenarios exist for other kinds of particle or primordial black holes. https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/the-origins-of-dark-matter?language_content_entity=und

Comment: *I thought to post some question in order to gain some knowledge in order to think systematically.* I recommend first learning about physics that is well-understood, and only later inquiring about physics that is poorly understood. Some physicists do not accept that dark matter exists at all! They instead prefer to consider revisions to the theory of gravity.

Answer (score 2):

The [big bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) is not a process of creation out of nothing, it's the process responsible for the initial evolution. A candidate for such a process is the inflation theory. So is not the big bang that created dark matter, nor ordinary standard model matter. They presumably were already there, but we don't know if our laws of physics hold at such energies. A more accurate question should be if both ordinary and dark matter were present both at such energies.

Nonetheless, we currently don't even know what dark matter is, and if it is a particle after all, so to ask if it was there during the big bang event is a too early question: we don't know what it is yet.

Comment: But there are models and formation scenarios depending on the candidate dark matter particles or even primordial black holes. An answer should discuss these, with citations.